# oracle trunc(sysdate) to linq entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am not familiar with oracle sql and have to convert

```
oracle sql trunc(sysdate) to linq
```

I thought it was (d.ScheduledDate > = DateTime.Now.Date) but it was wrong.

I am not sure what is the conversion TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1095

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trunc` removes the time component, and then `-1095` subtracts 1095 days.  So in LINQ something like:

```
where d.ScheduledDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1095)
```